# Phone gap set working directory

Tags: cordova, filesystems

Ok using /image_location.png is the root of the device and not the root of the www folder. Is there then a way to set the working directory of my application to the www folder?

Comment: I too would love to know if this is possible.  Perhaps in Cordova?

Comment: i am thinking an asset pipeline library like rubies may exist that could be nice. it would be a bummer though to have to work in something like that though

Comment: Yeah, I have just been using `file:///android_asset/www/...` since I am only developing on Android for now.  It's worked great for me in my test cases, but it's def not a permanent/optimal solution.

Answer (score -1):

just use the relative path `image_location.png` instead of `/image_location.png`

If you're using the path for example from inside a css file located in `www/resources/css/` for then you can use `../../image_location.png`

Comment: OK sorry for trying to help.